# My dog eats dirt from weird places then throws up

Tags: dogs, safety, eating

Recently, my female dog gave birth to a pup, which is about one and half to two months old by now. Every morning I take him on a walk near the neighborhood to get him acquainted with smells. However, my dog also likes to taste dirt from weird places (including some very gross ones). Also, only today I discovered that he was excessively vomiting (has happened three times today as of now), which has me excessively worried.

What should I do?

Comment: Have you asked your veterinarian about the vomiting? You will want to train the dog to not eat things you don't feed it. Your vet should be able to recommend a good local resource for dog and dog owner training. Congratulations on the puppies!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not let them eat dirt.  Puppies (as I've discovered) like to eat and bite things that they otherwise really shouldn't.  It's how they learn.  You need to get your puppy into the mindset that eating abnormal objects isn't allowed.

Sternly tell your puppy not to eat something when they do or if it looks like they are about to.  I've been doing this with my new puppy and so far it's been working pretty well.